# php date string sql server 2008 insert

Tags: php

Trying to insert date as a string from array to SQL Server 2008 and getting this error

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 22007 [SQLSTATE] => 22007 [1] => 241 [code] => 241 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. ) )

The insert array is like this

```
$data = array(
    'date' => '2012-10-12',
    'time' => '10:37:10'
);
```

date field datatype date
time field datatype time(7)

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test (p_date, p_time) VALUES (?, ?)";

$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql, array(&$data['date'], &$data['time']));

if( sqlsrv_execute($stmt) === false) 
{
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Comment: don't put into a comment. it's unreadable. edit your question and put it there.

Comment: What are the data types of the columns of the `test` table?